# Правильна ли конструкция с двумя тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

*Мой дом — халупа — моя крепость.*

Верна ли такая конструкция с двумя тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш случай, вероятно, подпадает под правило об уточняющих членах предложения, см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/).

> Уточняющие члены при подчеркивании смысла выделяются или отделяются тире: Они [статуи] были расставлены прямо на земле и на газонах – без пьедесталов – в каком-то продуманном беспорядке (Кат.) – уточняется обстоятельство; Мины же все в снегу, который тут совсем неглубокий – до щиколотки (В. Бык.) – уточняется сказуемое; Памятников, правда, было мало – всего пять-шесть (Пауст.) – уточнение в нерасчлененном односоставном предложении» [ ПАС 2011: 221–222].

**ВЫВОД**

Предложение корректно составлено, если подразумевается, что "дом" — это уточняющий член предложения, относящийся к "моему дому". Другими словами, вставка "дом" разбивает на две части выражение "мой дом — моя крепость", при этом соотносясь с первой его частью. Поэтому знаки расставлены верно:

*Мой дом — халупа — моя крепость.*

Также возможны и другие корректные варианты, например:

*Мой дом, халупа, — моя крепость.* (Запятыми выделяем уточняющий оборот и сохраняем тире из выражения.)

*Мой дом, — халупа, — моя крепость.* (Тут использована так называемая симметрия знаков: когда оборот с обеих сторон закрывается запятой и тире, см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=205425).)

Comment: Похоже на перечисление маршрута. А здесь нужно как-то определить (знаками и интонацией) деление на две, а не на три части, обозначив подлежащее и сказуемое.

Comment: Теоретически тут возможно перечисление маршрута по типу Москва — Казань — Челябинск (и тире также сохраняются). Все вопросы к контексту. Но если у нас перечисление маршрута, получается, что персонаж перемещается из своего дома в какую-то халупу, а из неё — в собственную крепость. Как-то странновато... Так что гораздо больше напоминает просто уточняющий член предложения (то есть его дом — хоть и халупа, но всё равно — крепость, место, где он в безопасности).

Comment: Я говорю о том, что  запись предложения выглядит некорректно, хотя мы можем догадаться о его содержании. Нет разделения подлежащего и сказуемого, то есть грамматика не обозначена. Вам-то самим оно нравится, вы бы так написали?  Есть ли что-нибудь подобное в Нацкорпусе? Попробуйте найти другую форму.

Comment: В своём ответе я предложил и другие варианты, так что есть, из чего выбрать, — что больше нравится.

Comment: Я не видела исправленный вариант. Ну что ж, пусть автор вопроса выбирает, хотя симметрия знаков вызывает сомнение.  Но мне эти варианты  тоже не нравятся, искусственно они как-то выглядят. Уточнение кажется странным — что мы уточняем?  Содержание, как мне кажется, не то, что мы прочитаем в этой записи.

Answer (score 2):

[**ХАЛУПА**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0&all=x) — это не какое-то определённое жилище. Это слово является оценкой, характеристикой жилого помещения. Оно не может в данном случае выступать в роли уточнения или пояснения. С двумя тире или запятыми и тире получается так: у меня есть несколько домов, среди которых *халупа*. Но ведь это не соответствует смыслу. Единственное, что может оправдать уточняющий характер, — это контекст, например:
— Твой дом — халуха!
— Мой дом, "халуха", — моя крепость. = Мой дом (как ты говоришь, "халупа") — моя крепость.

*Мой дом — халупа.*
*Моя халупа — моя крепость.*

Вот такие предложения корректны.

Поэтому, думаю, следует поставить дефис, то есть считать *"халупу"* приложением:

***Мой дом-халупа — моя крепость.***

Comment: Александр, мы думаем с вами одинаково.  Я полагаю. что это единственно правильная и красивая запись

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Мне сразу запись с двумя тире резанула слух, и по смыслу тоже совсем не вяжется.

Comment: Точно! А все предложенные варианты не улучшили, а скорее ухудшили и смысл, и графику. Вот простое предложение, а здесь нужны и вкус, и чувство языка.

Comment: Можно и так, согласен, русский язык даёт множество вариантов. Я же в своём ответе просто-напросто пытался найти решение, оперируя только пунктуационными знаками в рамках одного предложения. Ну а дальше можно как угодно: поменять местами / добавить слова / разбить на предложения / добавить приложения через дефис и т. д. Молодцы, что расширили круг вариантов — так больше пространства для манёвра и выбора.

Comment: Какой круг вариантов? Здесь единственный вариант, который можно считать правильным. Все остальные не выдерживают никакой критики.